# Annotations and superclasses

Tags: python, typechecking

This is a question about best practice - consider I have the following base class module, `base.py`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if type_checking:
    from redis import Redis


class Base:
    redis: Redis

    def __init__(self, redis):
        self.redis = redis
```

Assuming I want a class that inherits from `Base` - which of the following is considered better and why? Is there another way I didn't think of?

(1.) seems cleaner but in (2.) I declare `redis: Redis` explicitly, which might be better for type-checking tools

1.

```py
from base import Base

class Sub(Base):
    user_id: int

    def __init__(self, redis, user_id):
        super().__init__(redis)
        self.user_id = user_id
```

2. 

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from base import Base

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from redis import Redis

class Sub(Base):
    redis: Redis
    user_id: int

    def __init__(self, redis, user_id):
        super().__init__(redis)
        self.user_id = user_id
```

Comment: Type checking tools should understand inheritance, there’s no use redeclaring the type hint again in the sub class.

Comment: DRY.  Typechecking tools know about the inherited attribute; they wouldn't be much use if they didn't!  Best practice should include annotating the params to `__init__` though.  :)

Answer (score 1):

As @deceze mentioned, type-checking tools should understand your inheritance model and handle the hint appropriately.

In terms of "best practices", your option 1 is perfectly fine since you don't have to re-declare `redis`.

If you want something cleaner, another option is to use `dataclasses`

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Base:
    redis: Redis


@dataclass
class Sub(Base):
    user_id: int
```

Reference docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

As covered, not re-declaring things in the subclass is preferable.  Since we're talking about best practices, though, I'll also suggest that if you're not using dataclasses and your instance attributes are being set in your `__init__`, that's where you should put your type annotations instead:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, redis: Redis):
        self.redis = redis

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, redis: Redis, user_id: int):
        super().__init__(redis)
        self.user_id = user_id
```

This is briefer since you don't need to declare each attribute in multiple places, and it gives you correct typechecking when you construct an instance:

```
s = Sub(Redis(), 42)
reveal_type(s.redis)    # note: Revealed type is "Redis"
reveal_type(s.user_id)  # note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
t = Sub("redis", 42)    # error: Argument 1 to "Sub" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Redis"
```

If the parameters aren't annotated, then you get the "correct" revealed type on the attributes, but it's very easy for them to have the wrong actual types at runtime:

```
t = Sub("redis", 42)   # no error (oops!)
reveal_type(t.redis)   # note: Revealed type is "Redis"
print(type(t.redis))   # <class 'str'>  (oops!)
```